# python/matplotlib: create graph with changing background colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have a graph with changing background colors depending on some variable, such as this one:[image]

My variable would determine whether the background is grey, red, or green for a particular X value. I know about `set_facecolor(color)`, but that only changes the entire background.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [fill_between()](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html) to fill the area between x axis. Here is a [demo](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html) of how you can do this with x axis

Answer (score 0):

You can use colorbar function of the matplotlib to create colored graphs. Something like this:

```
plt.colorbar();
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I will post the solution I ended up with if anyone else come here looking for this like I did.

This function can be used to color the plot vertical using a list of states.

```
def plot_state_as_color(x_data, state_data, axis, add_labels=True):
    state_current = state_data[0]
    span_left = x_data[0]
    state_encountered = []
    for span_right, state_next in zip(x_data, state_data):
        if state_current != state_next:
            label = None
            if state_current not in state_encountered:
                state_encountered.append(state_current)
                if add_labels:
                    label = state_current

            # plot section
            color = "C{}".format(state_encountered.index(state_current))
            axis.axvspan(span_left, span_right, facecolor=color, alpha=0.5, label=label)

            # Update current state parameters
            span_left = span_right
            state_current = state_next
```

Here is an example of how to use it.

```
# Generate some data for the example
x_values = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
y_values = np.abs(np.sin(x_values))
state = [round(3*v) for v in y_values]

# figure with 4 states
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
plt.plot(x_values, state, label="state")
plot_state_as_color(x_data=x_values, state_data=state, axis=ax)
plt.title("4 states")
plt.legend()
```

This code produces the following figure

[plot of 4 states as color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjIu3.png)

The state vector can also contain strings like this

```
# State with string values
state_display_name = {0: "Zero",
                      1: "One",
                      2: "Two",
                      3: "Three"}
state = [state_display_name[s] for s in state]
plt.figure()
ax = plt.gca()
plot_state_as_color(x_data=x_values, state_data=state, axis=ax)
plt.title("4 states using strings as states")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[example of strings as states](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifTnu.png)

One limitation is that the state color plot can't have gabs like in the graph from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code MWJürgensen, and it works perfectly. However, it is not coloring the last element of the "state". To solve this, I added two lines at the end of the function, and is working fine for me!

```
def plot_state_as_color(x_data, state_data, axis, add_labels=True):
state_current = state_data[0]
span_left = x_data[0]
state_encountered = []
for span_right, state_next in zip(x_data, state_data):
    if state_current != state_next:
        label = None
        if state_current not in state_encountered:
            state_encountered.append(state_current)
            if add_labels:
                label = state_current

        # plot section
        color = "C{}".format(state_encountered.index(state_current))
        axis.axvspan(span_left, span_right, color=color, alpha=0.3, label=label)

        # Update current state parameters
        span_left = span_right
        state_current = state_next

# plot last section
label = None
if state_current not in state_encountered:
    state_encountered.append(state_current)
    label = state_current
color = "C{}".format(state_encountered.index(state_current))
ax.axvspan(span_left, span_right, color=color, alpha=set_alpha, label=label)
```